# .net mvc codefirst multiple SiteDataContextInitializer one database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco, datacontext

I'm trying to create modules to reuse. For example, a Membership project that creates and handles user operations (login, register, etc), then build it, and use the dll inside other projects.

So, in the Membership project I create my POCO classes and the DataContext using its own Namespace:

```
namespace CloudOne.Membership.Models
{
    public class SiteDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserRoleJoin> UserRoleJoins { get; set; }

        // Twist our database
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class SiteDataContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SiteDataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SiteDataContext context)
        {
            // users

            var user = new User { UserID = "UserA", Password = "D33177D41FD48F0027BD10D2689E8599", DateCreated=DateTime.Now, DateLastLogin = DateTime.Now };

            context.Users.Add(user);

            var roles = new List<UserRole>
            {
                new UserRole { RoleID = "Admin" },
                new UserRole { RoleID = "Editor" },
                new UserRole { RoleID = "Customer" },
                new UserRole { RoleID = "Guest" }
            };

            roles.ForEach(m => context.UserRoles.Add(m));

            var userRoleJoin = new UserRoleJoin { UserID = "UserA", RoleID = "Admin" };

            context.UserRoleJoins.Add(userRoleJoin);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I use in a main project, using the CloudOne.Membership.dll as reference, the main project has its own Namespace, DataContext and seed again:

```
namespace CloudOne.Models
{
    public class SiteDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductPrice> ProductPrices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductPicture> ProductPictures { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

    public class SiteDataContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<SiteDataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(SiteDataContext context)
        {
            // data seeding here

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call both Initializers from global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<SiteDataContext>(new SiteDataContextInitializer());
            Database.SetInitializer<CloudOne.Membership.Models.SiteDataContext>(new CloudOne.Membership.Models.SiteDataContextInitializer());

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
```

Now the problem is, when I access a page that uses main project classes, it creates the database (ModelFirst) for the POCO defined in main class, and seeds the data as defined in the main project datacontext, but it doesnt create POCO or seed for Membership ones. And, when access a page that uses Membership data... it recreates the database for Membership only.

So, how I can use Membership (and other modules) together with a main project, without having to add tables, relationships and seeding manually for all is not in the main project?

For example, the main project is about Shopping Cart, in order to user Membership module, I have to copy all POCO classes inside ShoppingCart DataContext and also the seeding part to create users, roles, etc. But that code already is inside the Membership. Initializer, so how to encapsulate that, so that no need copy code from all module to the main app just to have the database with all tables and data?

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance this is a connection string issue and the DB is actually getting created just not in the place you're expecting.

My guess is that you have defined the `SiteDataContext` connection string in your web.config but you have not defined the `CloudOne.Membership.Models.SiteDataContext` connection string explicitly.

EF is going to consider these two separate DbContexts -- it's not like you can merge them simply by making the classes the same name.  So it's looking for separate connection strings to go along with the separate initialization instructions you are assigning.

I have not tried this with EF 4.1 but I believe model change tracking will prevent having two contexts share the same physical database ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8037717/941058)).

In short, I believe your immediate problem is that you're not initializing your Membership context with a connection string so it is defaulting to local.  EF will try to find a connection string with the name of your context in the active App Domain (your Shopping Cart website) so it needs to be in the web.config of that site.

Comment: Thank you for your time in answering. Yes, I agree with you, the problem is I don't find the way to declare one single string for all connections at a Solution level, so now it is at Project level, so as you say, is one different locally.

Comment: If your solution is around an MVC or ASP.NET web application then you just need to put the right connection string in the Web.config.  The name of the connection string is important -- it should match your DbContext name and may need to be qualified with the namespace.  If your solution is a console or desktop application than do the same but with App.config.  If this answers your question please check this answer as your solution.